# Login to Flask app with database credentials

Tags: python, flask

This may be more of a concept question as opposed to a "How do I" question. Currently, I am looking to create a flask app to help me create somewhat complex MongoDB entries. This worked well originally in my CLI based script when these entries were more simple. I am looking for a way to create a safer way to deploy this app on some docker containers without giving the application itself access to the database. The idea I am trying to work out is, can I create a flask app that has no access to the DB until the user logs in and, that users login credentials are the database credentials. I am struggling to work this out, if anyone could provide some insight I would be most thankful.

Comment: Why do you think you even need to do that? there's no problem with flask having database access all the time. Is there any special case which I can't see?

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")


# sqlalchemy
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

In general practice, we setup environment variables before running the application so that the code itself do not explicitly show database url.

In mac and linux this is done using

```
export DATABASE_URL=yourdatabaseurl
flask run
```

In windows

```
set DATABASE_URL=yourdatabaseurl
flask run
```